# Integral of a product of othogonal polynomials over the domain

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $\phi_i (x)$ with $x \in I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an i-th order orthogonal polynomials with respect to the weight function $w(x)$.

Is the following integral finite for any othogonal polynomial and every $n$? Why?

$\int_I \prod_{i=0}^{n} \phi_i (x) w(x) dx  $

for $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.

Comment: Yes, because the product of continuous functions is continuous. Integrating a continuous function over a finite interval is a number that's not infinity.

Comment: What if I = (-\infty,\infty) or I = [0,\infty) like for the Hermite and Laguerre polynomials, respectively?

Comment: In both the cases, you have weights that decays exponentially fast. Hence, it suffices to check $\int^\infty_0 P_n(x)e^{-x}\ dx<\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me just prove the following
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 P_n(x)e^{-x}\ dx <\infty 
\end{align}
for any polynomial $P_n(x)$. It suffices to prove the integral for $P_n(x)= x^n$. Observe
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 x^ne^{-x}\ dx =&\ \int^\infty_0 (-1)^n\frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{-tx}\bigg|_{t=1}\ dx = (-1)^n\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\int^\infty_0 e^{-tx}\ dx\\
  =&\ (-1)^{n} \frac{d^n}{dt^n} \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\bigg|_{t=1} = n!.
\end{align}